# Interpretation as a local variable overrides method name?

Tags: ruby, local-variables, self-reference

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050), when a local variable not defined is used within its own assignment, it is evaluated to `nil`.

```
x = x # => nil
```

But when the name of a local variable conflicts with an existing method name, it is more tricky. Why does the last example below return `nil`?

```
{}.instance_eval{a = keys} # => []
{}.instance_eval{keys = self.keys} # => []
{}.instance_eval{keys = keys} # => nil
```

Comment: I guess, there's some shortcut in parser/interpreter, which checks variables for self-assignment. http://pastie.org/4901726

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Ruby, because methods can be called without an explicit receiver and without parentheses, there is a syntactic ambiguity between a local variable reference and a receiverless argumentless method call:

```
foo
```

could *either* mean "call method `foo` on `self` with no arguments" or "dereference local variable `foo`".

If there exists a local variable `foo` in scope, this is *always* interpreted as a local variable dereference, *never* as a method call.

So, what does it mean for a local variable to "be in scope"? This is determined *syntactically* at *parse time*, *not* semantically at runtime. This is very important! Local variables are defined at parse time: if an assignment to a local variable is seen by the parser, the local variable is in scope from that point on. It is, however, only *initialized* at *runtime*, there is no compile time evaluation of code going on:

```
if false
  foo = 42 # from this point on, the local variable foo is in scope
end

foo # evaluates to nil, since it is declared but not initialized
```

Why does it make sense for local variables to "shadow" methods and not the way around? Well, if methods did shadow local variables, there would no longer be a way to dereference those local variables. However, if local variables shadow methods, then there is still a way to call those methods: remember, the ambiguity only exists for receiverless argumentless methods calls, if you add an explicit receiver or an explicit argument list, you can still call the method:

```
def bar; 'Hello from method' end; public :bar

bar # => 'Hello from method'

bar = 'You will never see this' if false

bar # => nil

bar = 'Hello from local variable'

bar      # => 'Hello from local variable'
bar()    # => 'Hello from method'
self.bar # => 'Hello from method'
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, because Matz defined it so. This behavior is one of the very few things I don't like about Ruby. It even gets better:

```
a = b if a
=> nil
a
=> nil
```

Variable `a` gets initialized to nil even though in theory a = b statement should under no circumstances be executed.

Comment: Well, in practice it's not executed either. If it actually got executed, then `a` would have the value of `b`; but it doesn't. What looks like execution is actually a scope change - if the expression `a` is referenced after `a = b`, it refers to the local. In the same way, the expression `Object` means something different at the top-level vs inside the module in this case: `module Foo; class Object; end; end`, due to differing scope. See Jörg W Mittag's answer.

Comment: Kelvin, you are mixing two unrelated things. You are right on the first one. `a = b if a` is actually too complicated an example. The weirdness is eg. that `a if a` fails, while `a = a if a` initializes `a` to nil, even though the contents of the `if` statement should not matter, since it never gets executed. I understood that even though it never gets executed, the compiler goes through it _in the left to right order_. So eg. `if b then b = b end` fails again. But as for `module Foo; class Object end end`, this is actually not an issue of _scope_, but one of _namespace_ -- you are simply...

Comment: ... defining a constant on the module `Foo`. It can be equivalently rewritten as `Foo = Module.new; Foo::Object = Class.new`.

Comment: Perhaps my example wasn't the best. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687276/scope-of-constants-in-ruby-modules/11677867#11677867), where I mention the pitfall. The inner module can't access the outer module's constant w/o a namespace when the inner isn't lexically enclosed by the outer. Some people might consider this odd, just like the auto-initialization of locals. But I guess my real point is, I'm not quite sure why you "don't like" the locals behavior - is there a real world use case where you'd actually want to get a `NameError` on `a`?

Answer (score 0):

I've adopted this pattern to ensure that scope is as I expect without polluting the codebase without lots of `self`

```rb
def some_class_method
  another_class_method_local = self.another_class_method
  # do stuff with the *_local variable
  self.another_class_method = another_class_method_local
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I think in your case it's because it's what's expected :P

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > {}.instance_eval{a=1}
 => 1 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > {}.instance_eval{a}     
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for {}:Hash
    from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):2:in `instance_eval'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/rafael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Instance eval evaluates code at instance level so each hash you are declaring is different. If you want to return keys this works

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > {}.instance_eval{keys = self.keys
1.9.3-p194 :004?>   keys = keys}
 => []
```