# erb layout variables are undefined and not nil

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

What I want to do is something like `variable || "default string"`.

But this works only if `variable` is nil and for some reason it's undefined.

Is it possible to set the default value to nil, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make profit of the fact that Ruby local variables [evaluate to `nil` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12708516/1279683) with:

```
variable ||= 'default string'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
defined?(variable) ? variable : "default string"
```