# Ruby Scope/Bindings

Tags: ruby

The output of the following snippet of Ruby code

```
def foo; "foo:function"; end
puts foo
puts foo()
foo = "foo:value"
puts foo
puts foo() # Didn't expect this to work!
```

is

```
foo:function
foo:function
foo:value
foo:function
```

This is puzzling, I would have thought that in the current scope there is only one binding for foo, but looks like this is not the case.

PS: Running equivalent code in python gives the expected result (i.e. after binding a string to foo, the last statement trying to call foo() gives an error).

**Edit**:

The following is the equivalent example in python:

```
def foo(): return "foo:function"
print foo
print foo()
foo = "foo:value"
print foo
print foo()
```

which produces the output (edited):

```
<function foo at 0x7fb71d912578>
foo:function
foo:value
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**Edit 2:**

So, it seems in Ruby, unlike Python, a given symbol can have two binds in the same scope (as a method and as an instance variable).

Comment: Using parens explicitly tells Ruby that you are calling a method.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try puts foo without the parentheses and you'll get "foo:value". With the () you're explicitly saying this is a method. Try putting these 2 lines at the end of your code:

```
puts defined? foo #=> local-variable
puts defined? foo() #=> method
```

You may find [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706664/interpretation-as-a-local-variable-overrides-method-name) to be useful, especially this part:

> Why does it make sense for local variables to "shadow" methods and not
>   the way around? Well, if methods did shadow local variables, there
>   would no longer be a way to dereference those local variables.
>   However, if local variables shadow methods, then there is still a way
>   to call those methods: remember, the ambiguity only exists for
>   receiverless argumentless methods calls, if you add an explicit
>   receiver or an explicit argument list, you can still call the method:

Comment: Addendum to last quoted sentence: "..or if you invoke the method on the receiver using `send`" (here `send :foo` or `send "foo"`). Good answer.