# Strange local variable behavior in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I noticed a strange behavior with Ruby local variables in the code below. It seems that Ruby runs into the false part and sets `params` to nil. The code in irb is below:

```
2.1.2 :001 > def params
2.1.2 :002?>   {a:1}
2.1.2 :003?> end
2.1.2 :014 > def go1!
2.1.2 :015?>   p params
2.1.2 :016?>   if false
2.1.2 :017?>     params = 1
2.1.2 :018?>   end
2.1.2 :019?>   p params
2.1.2 :020?> end
 => :go1! 
2.1.2 :021 > go1!
{:a=>1}
nil
 => nil
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12708516/2988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby determines the lifetime of local variables while it parses the code, so even if `params = 1` assignment wouldn't be reached, `params` will be interpreted as local variable (and set to `nil` by default) in this scope.

Here's the link to documentation:

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods

Comment: But shouldn't be not treated as a local variable if params is already available.

Comment: thanks for you link, my friend also give me a more detail explain. see https://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/syntree.html on local Variable Part.